# Text Control Reporting: The following control could not be licensed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting, txtextcontrol

I have a problem with text control reporting.
The problem is that locally the project I have included the license because what I do is visualize a file that I have in my database and I convert it to pdf to be able to visualize it and it works correctly but when I publish it on my site I can not use it of the license sending the following error: The following control could not be licensed: TXTextControl.TextControl I am not so sure that this is the error but I have searched everywhere and nothing that works for me.

Any suggestions? Has anyone had this problem before?

Attached screenshot of the license file included
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRkPt.png)

Comment: May help , https://www.textcontrol.com/blog/2007/05/29/tx-text-control-net-for-windows-forms-licensing/